# Winres.h copilation error in CryEngine EaaS

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, cryengine

I am new to Cryengine and I am trying to build custom `Game DLL` for my game.
But first, I tried to compile `CryGameZero DLL` and I came up with some compilation errors.

I am using **VS2013 Professional**.

```
Error RC1015: cannot open include file 'winres.h'.
    c:\...\CRYENGINE\BinTemp\rc_files\CryGameZero.auto_gen.rc 
    10 1 CryGameZero

Error MSB3073: The command "cd /d
    "c:\...\CRYENGINE" & cry_waf.exe 
    build_win_x86_profile --project-spec gamezero
    --execsolution="c:\...\CRYENGINE\Solutions\CRYENGINE.sln"
    --targets=CryGameZero" exited with code 1.
    c:\...\CRYENGINE\_WAF_\msbuild\waf_build.targets
    69 3 CryGameZero
```

I checked in my **VC++ Directories** and I had `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\include\um`
but `winres.h` was not in that directory so I changed to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um` where is `winres.h` located but I still get the same error.

Does anybody had the same problem or know how to fix this. I was searching on Google but so far I found documentation and tutorials on doing this with older versions of Cryengine without WAF and using VS2010 or VS2012.

Comment: This error is produced by the resource compiler (RC), not the C++ compiler.  Project > Properties > Resources > General > Additional Include Directories setting.

Comment: I don't have Resources under Project > Properties :(

Comment: But I have Additional Include Directory under Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > WAF

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this problem.

Here is the solution step by step.
First check for WAF configuration.

```
cry_waf.exe configure --auto-detect-verbose True
   --generate-vs-projects-automatically False
```

In my case, WAF was automaticaly detecting MSVC and Win SDK versions and fout

- MSVC 11.0
- MSVC 12.0

And automaticaly set it to MSVC 11.0 because that was first in the list.
The same goes with Win SDK versions, found

- SDK 8.0
- SDK 8.1

Amd automatically set to 8.0

Since I am using Visual Studio 2013, According to Crytek documentation you need to set versions of MSVC and Win SDK to suite your VS version

```
VS Version    VC++ Version    Recomended Win SDK
2012          11.0            8.0
2013          12.0            8.1
2015          14.0            10.0.10240.0
```

> **NOTE FOR VS2015**: Early installations of Visual Studio 2015 may have installed 10.0.10150.0 instead. In this scenario, re-run the
>   Visual Studio installer and select the recommended version.

Set that to appropriate versions, clean solution and build again made all as good as it needs to be.